# Can I install 'yajl-ruby' or 'json' on a remote user shell account without having root privileges?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

For some reason, I trust is for a good one which I fail to see, '*json*' and '*yajl-ruby*' ruby gems required by 'twitter' gem, in order to work properly, need root privileges.

I need to install and run the ruby script I prepared on a 24/7-up server and there's no better place from my remote paid host provider, which gives a shell. It's a FreeBSD 7.4 server.

I setup manually rubygems, the server only provided ruby1.8 via precompiled binary. So once I installed the gems I start using most of them without issues when I finally crossed 'twitter' I got this error:

$ gem install yajl-ruby 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing yajl-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
[...]
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -o root -g wheel -m 0755 yajl.so /path/.gems/gems/yajl-ruby-0.8.2/lib
install: /path/.gems/gems/yajl-ruby-0.8.2/lib/yajl.so: chown/chgrp: Operation not permitted
*** Error code 71

So I'm kinda stuck.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) you'll install gems without sudo.

It is very usefull and "must have" tool anyway :)

Also you can try to pass `--install-dir` option to your local dir with writing permissions

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I didn't knew about RVM, seems to be really amazing and solved the issue!